# Xcode Bots Error: unable to read module map contents from Target Support Files in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-ui-automation, xcode-bots

I am not able to run a test using `Xcode Bots` and `MacOS Server`. It is showing

> Error: unable to read module map contents from Target Support Files.

This error occurs for multiple files which are installed from cocoapods.

Comment: try removing pods, clean build then project and then adding pods again.

Comment: @iUser i tried doing that i even convert to latest swift syntax but it only works for few pods files, still having issues for remaining pods files.